# jQuery get a string property of a data attribute

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

What would be the most efficient way to get the  value `14500`from the `data-ls` attribute below. I have never seen multiple properties for a single data attribute before, and I am looking for the faster way to extract the value and not have it depend on the order of the data attribute properties.

```
<div class="slide" data-ls="slidedelay:14500; transition2d: all;"></div>
```

.

```
var duration = $('.slide').data('ls').split(';');
duration = duration[0].split(':');
console.log("duration: " + duration[1]);
```

thanks

Comment: There isn't a way to access the data inside `data-ls` as an object that I know of. You may simply have to exact it from the sting `"slidedelay:14500; transition2d: all;"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var duration = $('slide').data('ls').match( /slidedelay *: *(.*?);/ )[1];
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/km91mI7Q9JSAt_fr)

It returns the first matching string, so if you need it as a number, you need to use parseInt().

Comment: Thanks Laszlo..Not sure its faster than Robin's answer but I like the clean code.

Answer (score 3):

How about to do a loop on your split var then check the `key` if it's `slidedelay` to be sure.

e.g.

```
var duration = $('.slide').data('ls').split(';');
var slidedelay = "";
if(duration) {
    $.each( duration, function( key, value ) {
        val = value.split(':');
        if(val) {
          if(val[0] == "slidedelay") {
            slidedelay = val[1];
            return false;  // then break loop 
          }
        }
    });
}


console.log("duration: " + slidedelay);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt49kzb7/)

Answer (score 0):

> Try this one:

```
<div class="slide" data-ls="slidedelay:14500; transition2d: all;"></div>
```

> JS:

```
 var x = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].getAttribute("data-ls");
var x = x.split(":"); var val = x[1].split(';');
alert(val[0]);
```

JSFIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/Grald/cgy5drL4/1/

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. They want to get `14500`.

Answer (score 0):

Easy and quick way:
[**JSnippet Demo**](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/264/)

```
function getFrom(selector) {
    var val = null;
    var x = $(selector)[0]
             .getAttribute("data-ls")
             .split(' ')[0]
             .split(':');
    if (x.length > 1) val = parseInt(x[1]);
    return val;
}

$(function() {

    console.log(getFrom('.slide'));

});
```